# On Pseudometric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

How a pseudometrics induces topology? Can anyone discuss on this topic or give any good reference?

Comment: It's better to ask a specific question, like "How do pseudometrics induce topology?" with some supporting remarks explaining why the usual metric construction fails, than it is to ask for unspecified discussion.

Comment: -1: see Travis's comment.

Comment: Yeah. I have not asked directly and specifically. I'm sorry for that. But answer my question please.

Comment: @santanu: No need to be sorry, just edit your question. I will gladly reverse my downvote if you do that properly.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, we are not here to gain points or votes.

Comment: @santanu Of course not, but we are here to learn and help, and the rules for asking questions are in place to make both of those easier and more useful for everyone involved.

Comment: You can refer the chapter five of the book of general topology by Kuenn. I don't rember clearly, however, it seems to mentioned.

Comment: You can have a look at the Wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space). Interestingly, every pseudo-metric space induces a completely regular topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pseudometric (or a family of pseudometrics) induces a topology in the same way a metric does: it gives us a family of "balls" which form a basis of a topology.

A space with topology generated by a single pseudometric is not interesting: it's just a metric space with some points counted multiple times (we obtain the underlying metric space by identifying points at zero distance).

Those whose topology is generated by a family of pseudometrics are more interesting, for example, an uncountable product of metric spaces is of this kind. There is also the related concept of seminorms -- vector spaces with topology generated by a family of seminorms are common in analysis.